# Retrive BSON to Image MongoDB With PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

Am using php and MongoDB for my PoC. Can any one help me to retrieve BSON MongoBinData to  Image using PHP or JavaScript. I already insert the Image to MongoDB using below code.

```
     $profile = array(
     "username" => "foobity",
    "pic" => new MongoBinData(file_get_contents("C:\Elan\abstract-wallpapers-mobile.jpg"), MongoBinData::GENERIC),
);
$user = $dbs -> user;
$user -> save($profile);
```

Can anyone help me to convert the bson to Image using PHP or Javascript. I found number of posts with this topic, But no one have the retrieve method. Please add the Link if you found something helps you.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I use document less than 16MB, So i preferred MongoBinData instead of GridFs

Answer (score 0):

I found an link, which works well, on the other hand it was not using BinData, Looks like creator change the Image to base64 string and store then retrieve and show. if you have another ways please post here.

[link](https://gist.github.com/AlifArnado/61b791a040ce0c2ee7b7)

Answer (score 0):

Really thankful for this wonderful opportunity to help you guys out there with file/image insertion and retrieval back from mongodb using MongoBinData(less than 16mb)..So..First section shows you,how to insert a file into mongodb and second section will deals with image retrieval..Have a fun coding :D

```
***************** Image insertion**************
$frut=$_POST['fruit'];//just fruit name from a text box
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]); //from my index page i've Browse Image:<input type="file" id="img" name="img">

$m = new MongoClient();   
$db = $m->test_db;      //mongo db name
$collection = $db->fruits_image; //collection name

//-----------converting into mongobinary data----------------

$document = array( "fruit_name" => $frut,"image"=>new MongoBinData(file_get_contents($target_file)));

//-----------------------------------------------------------
if($collection->save($document)) // saving into collection
{
echo "One record successfully inserted";
}
else
{
echo "Insertion failed";
}

******************Image Retrieving******************

public function show()
{

$m=new MongoClient();
$db=$m->test_db;
$collection=$db->fruits_image;
$record = $collection->find();
foreach ($record as $data)
{
$imagebody = $data["image"]->bin;
$base64   = base64_encode($imagebody);
?>
<img src="data:png;base64,<?php echo $base64 ?>"/>
<?php
}
}
}
?>
```